# Sending files from wordpress server to another server

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to send some files from wordpress to another server, but i always get error
Here is example of my code:

```
$path = wp_upload_dir();
$file = @fopen($path['path'] . "/ORDERS.csv", "r");
$file_size = filesize($path['path'] . "/ORDERS.csv");
$file_data = fread($file, $file_size);
$args = array(
    'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8'),
    'body' => array('Customers' => $file_data, 'Orders' => $file_data, 'Products' => $file_data)
);
$result = wp_remote_post('https://example.com/upload', $args);
$login_token_response = wp_remote_retrieve_body($result);
```

I am always receiving error like this

```
{
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|8de9ae17-4a6692f375d9bc1b.",
    "errors": {
        "Orders": ["'Orders' must not be empty.", "Orders file can't be empty"],
        "Products": ["'Products' must not be empty.", "Products file can't be empty"],
        "Customers": ["'Customers' must not be empty.", "Customers file can't be empty"]
    }
}
```

Like I am doing something wrong, any ide?

Comment: What request format does the other server expect?

Comment: Files in that order I have writen

Comment: Not what I meant. Does it expect `application/json` to begin with? And just because you _say_ you were sending `application/json`, does likely not make `wp_remote_post` transform your request body content _into_ that automatically.

Comment: I dont know i have uploaded to that server from form, and have send to that server from form and jquey that vas like   const formData = new FormData();

Comment: With a form, it was most likely a `multipart/form-data` request then. If so, you will either have to assemble the correct format yourself then (http://codechutney.com/posting-file-using-wp_remote_post/), or use something like cURL instead of wp_remote_post in the first place.

Comment: I have tried to work on this
https://gerhardpotgieter.com/2014/07/30/uploading-files-with-wp_remote_post-or-wp_remote_request/

Comment: That one is sending `application/binary`, which means it can only be _one_ “object” to begin with, and there aren’t even any named parameters involved.